# Oracle: simulating a "post-commit" trigger

Tags: oracle

How can I get the equivalent of an "on commit" trigger after inserting some rows into a table?

After inserting several rows into a table, I would like to send a message to an external process that there are rows ready to process.  Using a statement-level trigger causes one message per insert, and I would like to send just one message saying "there are rows to be processed."

Comment: Why aren't you using queues?  See: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm

Comment: found 3 problems for us with queues:  (1) required apps to link in oracle runtimes, (2) latency time more than we liked, and (3) not scaling well to compute-farm size.

Comment: It seems queues don't solve the basic problem... coalescing multiple inserts so that there's only one message generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need to trigger an **external** process, have a look at [DBMS_ALERT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_alert.htm) instead of DBMS_JOB.

The external process would actively listen on the alert by calling a stored procedure. The stored procedure would return immediately after the alert has been signalled and commited.

Note that DBMS_ALERT is a serialization device. Thus, multiple sessions signalling the same alert name will block just as like they update the same row in a table.

Comment: This is the correct answer, because it allows for coalescing of multiple inserts. From the Oracle Doc: "Alerts can be signalled more often than the corresponding application wait calls. In such cases, the older alerts are discarded. The application always gets the latest alert (based on transaction commit times)."

Answer (score 7):

Create a job.  It won't actually be submitted until a commit occurs.  (Note: DBMS_SCHEDULER is usually better than DBMS_JOB, but in this case you need to use the old DBMS_JOB package.)

```
declare
  jobnumber number;
begin
  dbms_job.submit(job => jobnumber, what => 'insert into test values(''there are rows to process'');');
  --do some work here...
  commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use this to coalesce inserts?  I would like to process multiple inserts, and then do one "it's ready" step.

Comment: How is the work being done?  In a single transaction that you control (through a stored procedure or something), or just a simple insert statement by the users?  Would a table-level AFTER trigger work?

Comment: If there are a lot of transactions that you have no control over, maybe you could set the job to a minute in the future and have triggers check for the existence of the job in DBA_JOBS so they don't submit duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag to say "I've sent the message". 
To be sure you 'reset' the flag on commit, use dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id then you can simply do a

```
IF v_flag IS NULL OR dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id != v_flag THEN
  v_flag := dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id;
  generate message
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Oracle Advanced Queueing you can enqueue an array of records with a listener on the queue table.

The records will load, and the listener can then kick off any process you wish, even a web service call

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_aq.htm#i1001754